# Запрос захватывает ненужные логи

Tags: логирование, grep

Задача, из файла main.txt перенести все логи с ошибкой 500 в файл 500.txt(в main.txt так же находятся ошибки с кодом 400). Делаю запрос в консоли `grep "3[01]/12/2019:21:3" main.txt | grep '500' > ~/bug1/events/500.txt`. После, посмотрев в файл 500.txt внутри обнаруживаются логи с ошибкой 400. Вопрос: почему так и что нужно поменять в запросе чтобы захватывались **ТОЛЬКО** ошибки с кодом 500?

Пример лога из файла 400.txt.

```
80.57.170.51 - - [30/12/2019:21:35:12 +0000] "DELETE /users HTTP/1.1" 400 3623
204.235.176.118 - - [30/12/2019:21:35:13 +0000] "POST /users HTTP/1.1" 400 4704
82.95.203.67 - - [30/12/2019:21:35:19 +0000] "DELETE /lists HTTP/1.1" 400 3737
```

Пример лога из файла 500.txt.

```
65.47.42.12 - - [30/12/2019:21:37:39 +0000] "PATCH /customers HTTP/1.1" 400 2500
64.250.112.189 - - [30/12/2019:21:35:13 +0000] "PUT /parsers HTTP/1.1" 500 4639
193.253.101.180 - - [30/12/2019:21:35:31 +0000] "PATCH /alerts HTTP/1.1" 500 2944
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста в вопросе пример лога. Несколько строк. С оишбками 500 и 400. И желательно привести пример строки с ошибкой 400, который попадает в файл 500.txt

Comment: Потому что в первой строке написано "400 2**500**", очевидно же)

Comment: Каким образом можно это отсеять? @andreymal

Comment: Ну, пользуясь тем фактом, что статус всегда стоит после строки запроса, можно например загрепать кавычку `grep '" 500'` (хотя наверно лучше написать нормальную регулярку для парсинга, но мне лень)

Comment: @andreymal сейчас проверим.

Comment: @andreymal запрос: grep "3[01]/12/2019:21:3" main.txt | grep '"500' > ~/
bug1/events/500.txt - файл пустой.

Comment: @dmnsn46 если вы вдруг почему-то не заметили, между кавычкой и статусом вообще-то есть пробел

Comment: @andreymal сработало, спасибо! Не увидел потому что глаза в мыле уже от консоли, учимся только. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/3[01]\/12\/2019:21:3/ && $(NF-1) == 500' main.txt > 500.txt
```